# Describe the idempotents in a polynomial ring $R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, idempotents

> In general, given that $R$ is a commutative ring, how to identify the idempotent elements in $R[x]$?

I tried by solving equalities of polynomials but nothing works...

So how can I see that in which form can we get some idempotents in $R[x]$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compare the degrees of $p(x)$ and $p(x)^2$.

Comment: @Charter I have tried  that, but nothing works.

Comment: What exactly did you try and why it didn't work?

Comment: @Y.X. Hint: the idempotents of $R$ are the only idempotents in $R[X]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f^2 = f\,\Rightarrow f(0)^2\! = f(0) := a.\,$ If $\,f\!-\!a\ne 0\,$ it has order $\,k\ge 1,\,$ say $\,f = a + bx^k+\cdots,\,b\ne 0.\,$ Then $\,f^2\! = f\,\Rightarrow 2ab = b,\,$ times $\,a\,\Rightarrow\,2ab = ab\,\Rightarrow\,ab=0\,\Rightarrow\,b = 2ab = 0,\,$ contradiction. Therefore $\,f = a = f(0)\,$ is constant.

Comment: **Remark** $\ $ Note that the proof also works also for power series.

Comment: Since the word _order_ has multiple interpretations, I think it is important to note here that the order of $f-a$ refers to the exponent of the smallest degree monomial in $f-a$ with non-zero coefficient. Not the _degree_ of $f-a$, which is the largest such exponent (which of course doesn't make sense in the power series ring).

Answer (score -1):

**CASE I**:$R$ is an integral domain .Then $p(x)^2=p(x)\implies \deg p(x)=0\implies p(x) \text{is a constant}$

So the idempotents in $R[x]$ are only the idempotents in $R$.

**CASE II:**$R$ is not an integral domain .Here though the idempotents in $R$ will be idempotents in $R[x]$ it can't be said whether they will be the only idempotents or not.

Comment: Your case II is not correct; more can be said. A complete characterization of idempotents in polynomial rings is given in this MO answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138478/idempotent-polynomials